# Как с помощью кнопки JButton закрыть одно окно и открыть другое

Tags: java, jframe

Имеется проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в ExpRunner прописал

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        createDb();
        WindowAdd windowAdd = new WindowAdd();
        windowAdd.setVisible(true);
...
}
```

То-есть при запуске открывается WindowsAdd, там добавлена кнопка

```
    public class WindowAdd extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener {
    
        ...    

        private JButton bWindowDel = new JButton("Выкл");
        ... 
public WindowAdd() { 
...
            container.add(bWindowDel);
 ...
            bWindowDel.addActionListener(this); 
...}  

@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
...
            if (e.getSource() == bWindowDel) {
 //при нажатии на bWindowDel нужно, чтобы WindowsAdd закрылся, а WindowsOld открылся
    
    com.mrnats.starter.windows.WindowOld.getWindows(); // - не работает
    WindowOld.setVisible(true);  //не работает

    setVisible(false); // закрывает действующее окно WindowsAdd, тут все ок!
            }
    
    }
```

Окно закрывается, но WindowsOld не знаю как открыть, подскажите...

P.S.
Добавил

```
     new WindowOld();
```

и вроде все заработало!
И того:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == bWindowDel) {
        setVisible(false);
        new WindowOld();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решился добавлением

```
new WindowOld();
```